# Emulators are not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

In Android Studio the Emulators are not showing . I tried that disabling ADB Integration. but it is not working for me.

Please give me solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your project is not compatible (API version) with the target emulator. Check **build.gradle** file if the targetSDK and minimumSdk version is lower or equal to the sdk version of your Emulator.

Be sure that your compiledSdkVersion matches minSdkVersion and supported by targetSdkVersion. For example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "zeta.sqlitetest3"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```